# Postsharp validation and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, postsharp

I'm trying to validate in a good manner some models in a WPF application... I've read [this post](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Validation-with-PostSharp) of Alessandro Federicci andI think that's the way I should go... but I need to perform a little bit validation I need to warn if a Quantity is negative and an int property is set to 0 (I mean I need to validate a property using DataAnnotation agains another property) is this possible with PostSharp? How?

Thanks

Comment: yes. possible. that aspect would require a little reflection though + reading docs of course.

Comment: what you mean by reflection? on the class attribute I define?

Comment: well if i got your question right you need to consider 2 properties to know if a validation passes. the way to do that with aspects would require you to use reflection within the aspect you are declaring

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, you can do this using reflection. What is interesting though is that you can use advanced PostSharp features to bypass reflection.

If you implement `IAdviceProvider` you can provide `ImportLocationAdvice`. What this advice does is that it binds the location to a aspect's field of type `ILocationBinding`. This interface encapsulates a special class that provides a really fast access to the location (no reflection or runtime code generation is involved).

Let's say we want to have `MyValidationAspect` that takes a string argument which identifies a property which it should use as a secondary. It would be used like in the following example, where it will test `TestProperty` and `OtherProperty` are not equal.

```
public class TestClass
{
    [MyValidationAspect("OtherProperty")]
    public int TestProperty { get; set; }

    public int OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The following example demonstrates how to implement this logic. Note that it is not optimal as I will explain below. And, it does not include any sanity checks and build time errors.

```
[PSerializable]
public class MyValidationAspect : LocationInterceptionAspect, IAdviceProvider, IInstanceScopedAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    private string otherPropertyName;

    public ILocationBinding MyPropertyBinding;
    public ILocationBinding OtherPropertyBinding;
    private bool provideOther;

    public MyValidationAspect(string otherPropertyName, bool provideOther = true)
    {
        this.otherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
        this.provideOther = provideOther;
    }

    public IEnumerable<AdviceInstance> ProvideAdvices(object targetElement)
    {
        FieldInfo otherBindingField = typeof(MyValidationAspect).GetField("OtherPropertyBinding");
        PropertyInfo otherProperty = ((LocationInfo) targetElement).DeclaringType.GetProperty( this.otherPropertyName );
        yield return new ImportLocationAdviceInstance(otherBindingField, new LocationInfo(otherProperty));

        FieldInfo myBindingField = typeof(MyValidationAspect).GetField("MyPropertyBinding");
        yield return new ImportLocationAdviceInstance(myBindingField, (LocationInfo)targetElement);
    }

    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        if ( this.provideOther )
        {
            PropertyInfo otherProperty = ((LocationInfo) targetElement).DeclaringType.GetProperty( this.otherPropertyName );
            yield return new AspectInstance( otherProperty, new MyValidationAspect( ((LocationInfo) targetElement).Name, false ) );
        }
    }

    public override void OnSetValue( LocationInterceptionArgs args )
    {
        object instance = args.Instance;
        int newValue = (int)args.Value;
        int otherValue = (int)this.OtherPropertyBinding.GetValue(ref instance, Arguments.Empty);

        // perform the check
        if (newValue == otherValue)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        else
            args.ProceedSetValue();
    }

    public object CreateInstance( AdviceArgs adviceArgs )
    {
        return new MyValidationAspect( this.otherPropertyName );
    }

    public void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
    }
}
```

The aspect combines `IAdviceProvider` with `IAspectProvider` and shows how powerful meta-programming using PostSharp can be. The downside is though that currently it is not possible to use ImportLocationAdvice in aspects that are not instance-scoped, even though ILocationBinding expects instance reference. Therefore, two `MyValidationAspect` instances are created per target object instance. For brevity I will not explain possible workarounds.

I hope this example would get you on the track. If you need more details, please let me know and I will update this answer.